# Adding asinh (hyperbolic arcsin) link to glm

Tags: r, glm

I would like to adopt the hyperbolic arcsin (asinh) for some of my modeling. I have written the following function:

```
link.asinh <- function(mu)
{
linkfun<-function(mu) asinh(mu)
linkinv<-function(eta) sinh(eta)
mu.eta<-function(eta) sinh(eta)
valideta<-function(eta) TRUE
link <- paste0("lasinh")
structure(list(linkfun=linkfun, linkinv=linkinv, mu.eta=mu.eta, 
    valideta=valideta, name=link), class="link-glm")
}
```

But I'm at a loss from that point, how do I use this link in a Gaussian family glm, for example? I have read the ?family and ?make.link, no no avail.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15935574/2461552)?

Comment: No, I did not. THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH! I am so glad that it really is that simple to do. Just define an object as equal to your empty function and use that object as your new link! It's head smack time for me.