# user-defined "negative exponential" link glm

Tags: r, glm

I tried to follow this example [modify glm... user specificed link function in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931403/modify-glm-function-to-adopt-user-specified-link-function-in-r)
but am getting errors. I have binary data, and would like to change the link function from "logit" to a negative exponential link. I want to predict the

probability of success(p) = 1-exp(linear predictor)

The reason I need this link instead of one of the built-in links is that p increases in a convex manner between 0 and 0.5, but the "logit", "cloglog", "probit", and "cauchy" only allow a concave shape. See attached photo for reference: [predicted p vs binned observations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2rbt.jpg)

Simulate data

```
location<-as.character(LETTERS[rep(seq(from=1,to=23),30)])
success<-rbinom(n=690, size=1, prob=0.15)
df<-data.frame(location,success)
df$random_var<-rnorm(690,5,3)
df$seedling_size<-abs((0.1+df$success)^(1/df$random_var))
df<-df[order(df$location)]
```

Create custom link function. Note: eta = linear predictor, mu = probability

```
negex<-function(){
##link
linkfun<-function(mu) log(-mu+1)
linkinv<-function(eta) 1-exp(eta)
## derivative of inverse link with respect to eta
mu.eta<-function(eta)-exp(eta)
valideta<-function(eta) TRUE
link<-"log(-mu+1)"
structure(list(linkfun=linkfun,linkinv=linkinv,
             mu.eta=mu.eta,valideta=valideta,
             name=link),
        class="link-glm")
}
```

Model success as a function of seedling size

```
negexp<-negex()

model1<-glm(success~seedling_size,family=binomial(link=negexp),data=df)
```

> Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values

Model using glmer (My ultimate goal)

```
model2<-glmer(success~seedling_size+ (1|location),family=binomial(link=negexp),data=df)
```

> Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  : 
>     (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

I get different error messages, but I think the problem is the same regardless of whether using glmer or glm, and that is that my link function is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. Most helpful was this [R thread from 2016](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-October/422844.html). There were 2 issues. First, my link fuction was wrong. I revised it to this:

```
negex <- function() 
 { 
 linkfun <- function(mu) -log(1-mu) 
 linkinv <- function(eta) 1-exp(-eta) 
 mu.eta <- function(eta) exp(-eta) 
 valideta <- function(eta) all(is.finite(eta)&eta>0) 
 link <- paste0("negexp") 
 structure(list(linkfun = linkfun, linkinv = linkinv, 
             mu.eta = mu.eta, valideta = valideta, name = link), 
        class = "link-glm") 
}
```

Second, the model required specific starting values. These will be unique to your data. Here is the first few lines of the data that I actually found the solution to:

```
   site plot sub_plot oak_success oak_o1_gt05ft..1
  0001   10        3           1                0
  0001   12        2           0                0
  0001   12        3           0                0
  0001   12        4           0                0
  0001   13        4           0                0
```

I don't know how to post the full data to this site, but if someone wants it to run the example, shoot me an email: lake.graboski@gmail.com

```
negexp<-negex()
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future, because I found no other examples of this being solved on stack overflow or online. Using the new starting values, I was able to get the model to run:

```
starting_values<-c(1,0) #1 for the intercept and 0 for the slope
h_gt05_solo_negex2<-glm(oak_success~ oak_o1_gt05ft..1 , 
                    family=binomial(link=negexp),start=starting_values,data=rocdf)
summary(h_gt05_solo_negex2)
Call:
glm(formula = oak_success ~ oak_o1_gt05ft..1, family = binomial(link = negexp), 
data = lt40, start = starting_values)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.3808  -0.4174  -0.2637  -0.2637   2.5985  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      0.034774   0.005484   6.341 2.28e-10 ***
oak_o1_gt05ft..1 0.023253   0.002187  10.635  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 1416.9  on 2078  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1213.5  on 2077  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1217.5

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

There were some issues with convergence. As seedling heights (oak_o1_gt05ft..1) got above 40ft, the parameter estimates became unreliable [convergence issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEqy4.png). I had very few observations in this range, so I restricted the data to observations were the predictor was <40ft and re-ran the model. I also included "site" (same as "location" in the simulated data)). What you see in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTTDV.png) are the predictions of oak success with respect to oak seedling heights for each site/location (black circles), the binned observations of successes/samples (large green dots) and the prediction of success probability without a site factor (blue line). It looks like the slope of the seedling size variable is more accurate when site is factored in.

Unfortunately, I was not able to get this model to run in glmer, so site had to be included as a fixed effect, thus, the standard errors and slope estimates for oak seedling height might be a bit conservative.